# Deriving class from virtual base with no default constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance, ctor-initializer

I'm writing a small hierarchy of exception classes for a C++ application I'm developing, and I'm having trouble deriving indirectly from `std::runtime_error`. Here is code analogous to what I've written so far:

```
class RuntimeException : public virtual boost::exception, public virtual std::runtime_error {
public:
    virtual ~RuntimeException() {}
    RuntimeException() : runtime_error("A RuntimeException occurred.") {}
    RuntimeException(const std::string& what) : runtime_error(what) {}
};

class IllegalArgumentException : public virtual RuntimeException {
public:
    IllegalArgumentException() : RuntimeException("An IllegalArgumentException occurred.") {}
    IllegalArgumentException(const std::string& what) : RuntimeException(what) {}
};
```

The `RuntimeException` class compiles without issue, but `IllegalArgumentException` refuses to compile on VS2015, generating the error: `no default constructor exists for class "std::runtime_error"` for both constructors of `IllegalArgumentException`. This challenges my understanding of C++ inheritance hierarchies, as I expected this code to compile fine.

My understanding is that `IllegalArgumentException` *should* compile because, although it is true that `std::runtime_error` does not have a default constructor, its constructor is being called by the constructor for `RuntimeException`. But obviously this must be false, as the compiler is rejecting it. It seems to want me to call the `std::runtime_error` constructor directly from the `IllegalArgumentException` constructor (the compiler error goes away when I do so), but this seems wrong because then I would be calling the constructor for `std::runtime_error` twice: once in the constructor for `RuntimeException`, and again in the constructor for `IllegalArgumentException`.

Is this safe and/or efficient to do? If not, why does the compiler seem to encourage it? I *could* just derive from `std::exception` and implement the `std::string` myself as a member variable, but I thought it would be easier to derive from a standard class that has already implemented this. Is this the wrong approach to take? Additionally, is the fact that I'm deriving virtually from both `boost:exception` and `std::runtime_error` contributing to this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `virtual` inheritance the constructor call of the `virtual` base is the responsibility of the *most derived* class rather than the responsibility of any intermediate class. The reason is obvious: the use of `virtual` inheritance indicates that there is an expectation that there are actually multiple derived classes using the base class. Which one of these derived classes would be responsible for constructing the `virtual` base?

So, the constructor of any of the derived classes needs to provide an argument to the `virtual` base, e.g.:

```
IllegalArgumentException::IllegalArgumentException(std::string const& what)
    : std::runtime_error(what)
    , RuntimeException(what) {
}
```

To avoid having intermediate bases call the constructor of the `virtual` base classes intended for `virtual` inheritance often provide a default constructor. Of course, that opens up the possibility that the most derived class incorrectly relies on the proper constructor being called by one of its bases.

Comment: Thank you for this, your explanation is very clear. In light of this, I'm most likely going to end up deriving from `std::exception` and using my own `std::string`. It seems the simplest way to go.